# Having issues with Rewrite Rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How do I make htaccess include the post name when rewriting the url? Currently I am using a code-canyon purchased platform which does not come with SEO Friendly urls how ever the product is amazing otherwise.

Here is the code before any htaccess changes.

```
<a href="'.$this->url.'/index.php?a=track&id='.$row['id'].'" id="song-url'.$row['id'].'" target="_blank">'.$this->title.'</a>
```

I am looking to get my tracks page "Which is the content page in this example" to display in the url something like http://www.example.com/tracks/song-name-here
but instead it displays something like this http://www.example.com/index.php?a=track&id= and the ID Does not even generate the post name it's just a random number.

Here is my current rewrite rules for the url http://www.example.com/index.php?a=track&id=

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?a=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

You can check out the product in which I have purchased over at http://codecanyon.net/item/phpsound-music-sharing-platform/9016117 if you would like more information to help me out.

Comment: Did the phpSound script give you the slug of your track ? Could you show us your `$row` using `var_dump` ?

Comment: @Akmozo is there any chance that you could contact me over email so I could send you the phpSound content page? I have basically zero coding know how when it comes to what you're asking.

Comment: If you have zero coding know, so how you will be able to do what you are looking for ;) you should have a minimum php coding skills !! Are you sure that you are capable to do what we will, may be, tell you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this without adding this functionality to the PHP code you are using. I clicked the "support" tab on the codecanyon.net page and the author clearly states in the FAQ:

> URL’s rewrite 
>   Due to multiple server environment which requires
>   different rewrite url’s I decided not to include this feature at the
>   moment (it can be easily implemented), however this feature will be
>   taken in consideration for implementation in further updates.

You cannot do this with rewrite rules only - the software needs to maintain a own 1-1 mapping of SEO-friendly URLs to ugly URLs. Most frameworks and CMS like Wordpress, Drupal, etc, provide this as a feature. PhpSound explicitly does not offer this functionality.

Comment: he states in the comments section to another person who has asked this.

**Yes, you first need the rewrite rules (these depends on your server configuration), and then simply rename all the links from the current form into the rewritten ones.**